# WPF filling DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have an issue. I am trying to fill datagrid with data.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="54,74,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="347" Height="206" />
```

I do load the data from database and add them to the grid like that?

```
 List<Employee> employees= Modules.OleDatabase.loadEmployeesInside();
            foreach (var empl in employees)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(empl.Person_number);
                dataGrid.Items.Add(empl);
            }
```

But I just get this output in grid: [image]

Althougt all the data is definetly loaded right. Output in debug:

[image]

I did try using

```
ObservableCollection<Employee>
```

instead of list as well, but the same output. Can someone help me please?

My Employee class

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Person_number;
    public string Status, Name, Surname;
}
```

I did binding now

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="54,74,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="347" Height="206">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Person_number" Binding="{Binding Person_number}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Status" Binding="{Binding Status}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Surname" Binding="{Binding Surname}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

but the output is still like that.:
[image]

Comment: Have you implemented IPropertyChanged? I don't seem to see it anywhere.

Comment: Thats new term for me, I will look into that

Comment: @Sinnich well i it really necceseary? The grid should update itself on ItemSource change

Comment: if Peregrine's answer isn't doing it for you, I would recommend looking into it.

Comment: Wpf is designed to work with MVVM pattern. Take a look upon [www.learnmvvm.com](http://www.learnmvvm.com), or use other web resources to get to know MVVM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the `ItemsSource` property of your `DataGrid` to the list of items.

The following works fine for me ...

DataItem.cs

```
public class DataItem
{
    public DataItem(int id, string description)
    {
        Id = id;
        Description = description;
    }

    public int Id { get; }
    public string Description { get; }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<DataGrid Margin="16"
              x:Name="TheDataGrid" />
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataItems = new ObservableCollection<DataItem>();
        TheDataGrid.ItemsSource = DataItems;
        LoadDataItems();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<DataItem> DataItems { get; }

    private void LoadDataItems()
    {
        DataItems.Add(new DataItem(1,"One"));
        DataItems.Add(new DataItem(2, "Two"));
        DataItems.Add(new DataItem(3, "Three"));
        DataItems.Add(new DataItem(4, "Four"));
        DataItems.Add(new DataItem(5, "Five"));
    }
}
```

Comment: I was trying that as well, did try once more. It is still the same weird output. Like the image

Comment: That sounds like you assigned the list before you populated it. Using an ObservableCollection will address that.

Comment: Well I do get right amount of rows. I do assign the list after populating.I was trying to use ObservableCollection too.

Comment: So start with this basic version and add each step from your application one at a time until it breaks.

Comment: Ok, I got it working, I dont know how is you solution different from what I was trying the whole time, but it works. Thanks. Anyway, is there way, while assinging item source to specify row color depending on value?

Comment: if you want to change the row color based on a value, you might want to search for the term IValueConverter.

Answer (score 0):

How does your Employee class look like? Seems like it doesn't have any Properties that the Grid can auto generate columns for.

Edit: You should be using Properties and not fields in the Employee class like this:

```
public class Employee
    {
        public int Person_number { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: I think you have to use properties, see my edit in the original answer